# fullcalendar mysql select WHERE current date range

Tags: jquery, mysql, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have fullcalendar working with mysql database using php to fetch data from the database. I am trying to modify the select with data from fullcalendars 'getview'.
I need the current views first day of the month and I am trying to implement this code:

```
resources: 
            { 

                url: 'resources.php',
                data: {'period_start': moment( $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView").intervalStart ).format("YYYY-MM-DD"), 'period_end': moment( $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView").intervalEnd ).format("YYYY-MM-DD") } ,
            //  data:{'period_start':test},
                type: 'POST',

                error: function() {
                    $('#script-warning').show();
                }
            },
```

Unfortunately this always gives me the current date not the start of the view or anything else. what am I missing here?

everything goes to mysql perfectly and the select works with post. the only thing is that it will always give me the today's date, which is useless.

If i use this code, it works perfectly. when clicking on an event, it will give me the current view's first day:

```
eventClick: function(event) {
        alert(moment( $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView").intervalStart ).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
            },
```

EDIT:

I added a function:

```
function start(){
var view =$("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView").start;
return view};
```

When I use start() in eventclick, it works perfectly, but not when I use in resources. I am guessing I have to build the resources up as a function ([link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/resources_function/)) but I am too noob to understand this. Can I even somehow use function to get the feed from mysql?

Comment: it seems like it's undefined and moment.js just when formatting, gives it the today's date. where could i put the getview in order to actually get the info?

Comment: I'm assuming you specifically need resources, and can't just use events?

Comment: you are assuming correctly. i need this info in order to calculate something on the reaource column. i have a couple resource columns.

Comment: i already have a working myslq select function that just needs startpoint and end point in order to calculate what i need. the start and end have to be the first and last day of the month. if i could even get any date of the month thats being viewed, i would be happy. i can work from there. another option would be to do it via simple selects and build a function in js, but it looks like functions and variables cannot be used under resources?

Comment: and the perfect solution would be to get the first and last date of the view. for example if i have a year or three months etc.

Comment: functions can be used in resources but unfortunately it doesnt help me when i cannot use the 'getView' or 'getDate' method, which simply do not work there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out this half-a$$ solution. It will do, but it requires the user to make some unnecessary refreshes to get the latest info.

```
function start(){return Cookies.get('fullCalendarStart');};

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
viewRender: function(view) {
            Cookies.set('fullCalendarStart', view.intervalStart.format(), {path: ''});
            },

resources: 
            { 
                url: 'resources.php',
              data:{'period_start':start()},
                type: 'POST'
            }

{)
```

This will post the view's start date to resources.php post, where I can take it and use it in mysql select. You can add whatever you like from Fullcalendar, put it in cookies and use in mysql select this way.

Unfortunaly this is not the perfect solution and I'm still hoping to get it working without cookies.

EDIT

And a better solution:

```
resources: function(callback){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
                    $.ajax({
            url: 'feed.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                start: view.start.format(),
                end: view.end.format(),
                timezone: view.options.timezone
                }

            }).then(function(resources){callback(resources)});      
        },0);
    },
```

This will add start and end parameters like when fetching events. You can add 
`$feed_start = $_GET['start'];` to feed.php
and use the variable `'$feed_start'` in mysql select.
I got the input from https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/246?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container